# read strings from console without for loop

Tags: f#

Is there any elegant functional way to read N strings from console input? [F# for fun and profit](http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com) recommends to avoid for-loops, so i used recursion but it looks ugly and long.

Code description: I need to read several strings from console (exact number is specified in first line of input from console), concatenate them and convert to array of integers.

```
let rec recReadline n =
    match n with
        | 0 -> ""
        | _ -> let x = n - 1
               " " + Console.ReadLine() + recReadline x 

let getArrayOfIntFromConsole = 
    let x = Console.ReadLine() |> int |> recReadline
    let trimmedString = x.Trim()
    let numArray = trimmedString.Split ' ' |> Array.map(int)
    numArray
```

I'm learning f#, sorry for noob question.

**Update1**

Thanks for replies! This was task from hacker rank: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/diagonal-difference. At first i decided to separate input and algorithm logic and created this post. I was not clear enough describing context of the question and was advised to use Array.Init. It did not help me because input string consists of many integers separated by space. I marked one reply with Array.Init as correct answer because it was correct answer for my poor formulated question.

I decided to read console and compute in one function and it worked ok for me.
My final code:

```
open System

let rec recDiagDif recCounter primaryDiagSum secondDiagSum =
    match recCounter with
        | 0 -> primaryDiagSum - secondDiagSum |> abs
        | _ -> let arrayInt = Console.ReadLine().Split ' ' |> Array.map(int)
               recDiagDif (recCounter-1)
                          (primaryDiagSum + arrayInt.[arrayInt.Length - recCounter])
                          (secondDiagSum + arrayInt.[recCounter-1])

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    let matrixSize = Console.ReadLine() |> int
    printf "%A" (recDiagDif matrixSize 0 0)
    0
```

If you know how to improve code, please feel free to comment.

Comment: smells very much like https://courses.edx.org/courses/course-v1:Microsoft+DEV207.1x+1T2016/info...

Comment: no, it was task from hr: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/diagonal-difference

Comment: You might want to wrap your `Console.ReadLine() |> int` in a `try...with |> System.FormatException -> printfn "Invalid number!"` to catch bad input.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would be inclined to suggest keeping the console input as some kind of collection, rather than converting to a flat string only to then split again on whitespace.

```
let readNLines n =  Array.init n (fun _ -> Console.ReadLine())

let getArrayOfIntFromConsole() = 
    let lines = Console.ReadLine() |> int |> readNLines
    let numArray = lines |> Array.map(int)
    numArray
```

Answer (score 5):

You could do something like this:

```
open System

let getArrayOfIntFromConsole () = 
    let readLines n = Array.init n (fun _ -> System.Console.ReadLine ())
    Console.ReadLine () |> int |> readLines |> Array.map int
```

Demo (FSI):

```
> getArrayOfIntFromConsole ();;
3
1
42
1337
val it : int [] = [|1; 42; 1337|]
```

Comment: How would one do this with an unknown number of lines and without an escape sequence?

Comment: @rowRobot That depends on how to exit.

Comment: This is all about solving a HackerRank problem where  input is provided to standard input as a bunch of integers, one per line. You have to be logged in to see this page https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/fp-list-replication/problem

Comment: Why does the second parameter to Array.init need to be a lambda function. Why can the reference to Console.ReadLine not be passed directly to Array.init ?

Comment: @user645527 Are you asking about why I didn't eta-reduce the lambda expression? Have you tried yourself?

Comment: @MarkSeemann, thanks for response, no not about eta-reduce, I have tried myself, your solution is perfectly fine, but I tried to replace the lambda function with direct reference to Console.ReadLine which is incorrect. I think I see the point now, Array.init second parameter type does not match Console.ReadLine, thanks, appreciate much.

Answer (score 1):

You could create an infinite sequence which is fed from `Console.ReadLine` and just take the first `n` elements like so

```
let readNStrings n =                       
    fun _ -> Console.ReadLine()
    |> Seq.initInfinite
    |> Seq.take n
```

Comment: I'm not sure that's a good idea, lazy evaluation and IO make a dangerous combination for seasoned developers, nevermind people new to F#. There is no guarantee how many times `Console.ReadLine()` executes in this example or even when it does so.